# How to check the array within array if the value is the same on the newArray

Tags: javascript

How I can scan my array within array if there is equal array element.
I want to check if its true or false

```
// the array to be scan 
const array = [
[0, 1, 2],
[3, 4, 5], 
[6, 7, 8],
]

// the new array
const newArray = [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Have you checked [how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)？

Comment: not yet, but my problem is, the array is inside of array so what will I need to do to it in order to compare it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on anwser from [**how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript),you just need to iterate the first array and then compare them

```js
const array = [
[0, 1, 2],
[3, 4, 5], 
[6, 7, 8],
]

// the new array
const newArray1 = [0, 1, 2]
const newArray2 = [0, 1, 3]

const checkArray = (array1,array2) => {
  for(let arr of array1){
   if(arr.length === array2.length && arr.every((v,i) => v === array2[i])){
     return true
   } 
  }
  return false
}

console.log(checkArray(array,newArray1))
console.log(checkArray(array,newArray2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use every method to check all the items.

```js
array.filter((arr)=>arr.every((item,index)=>newArray[index]===item))
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the `newArray` has same elements at the index but has more elements: `array = [[1]], newArray = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

run a foreach or for loop  with a combination of `name.find(x => x.ref === value);`
or use `array.filter((arr)=>arr.every((item,index)=>newArray[index]===item))`

Comment: Doesn't work when the `newArray` has same elements at the index but has more elements: `array = [[1]], newArray = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
];

const newArray = [0, 1, 2]

let isPresent = false;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (JSON.stringify(array[i]) == JSON.stringify(newArray)) {
    isPresent = true
    break
  }
}
console.log(isPresent)
```

After stringifying the array you are able to compare directly in js and If it matches I changed the boolean value to true.

In case you have any doubts feel free to comment.